# Why does it keep telling me attempt to index nil with 'wins'?

Tags: lua, roblox

I have it so it loops through the players to check who's alive or not.

```
local function checkAlive()

    local Player = game.Players:FindFirstChild("leaderstats")
    for i,v in pairs(game.Players:GetChildren()) do
        if v.Character then
            if v.Character.Humanoid.Health > 0 then
                Player.wins.Value = Player.wins.Value + 1
            end
        end 
    end
```

But it keeps telling me attempt to index nil with 'wins'?

Comment: Are you deleting player objects when they die?

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: Can you post the code for the player objects?

Comment: local function onPlayerAdded(player)
 local leaderstats = Instance.new("Folder")
 leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"
 leaderstats.Parent = player

 local wins = Instance.new("IntValue")
 wins.Name = "Wins"
 wins.Value = 0
 wins.Parent = leaderstats

end

Comment: is it that? wdym

Comment: local Players = game:GetService("Players") I have this as well

Comment: You might have better luck using a table to hold the player parameters

Comment: Is `game.Players:FindFirstChild("leaderstats")` nil?

Answer (score 0):

```
    
local Player = game:GetService("Players")

local function checkAlive()
    for i,v in pairs(Player:GetPlayers()) do
        local leaderstats = v:FindFirstChild("leaderstats")
        if v.Character then
            if v.Character.Humanoid.Health > 0 then
                Player.wins.Value = Player.wins.Value + 1
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].